# Objective C: How to check for Leaks or Bad Access Errors

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-leaks

Need some advise here. Can you recommend some tools or methods to detect memory leaks and more importantly check for 'EXC_BAD_ACCES' errors.

Is NSZombie recommended? I tried to use that was not able to run the malloc history.

Any advise is greatly appreciated!

Zhen Hoe

Comment: Before using MallocStackLogging really try NSZombieEnabled, Analyze, and Instruments. It's easier. And yes, NSZombieEnabled helps a lot since most EXC_BAD_ACCESS come from over released pointers.

Comment: @Jano, thanks. I was having a little issue with the NSZomnbie... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6066699/objective-c-where-to-find-process-id-in-gdb. I could not seem to be able to run the malloc history command in gdb, any advise on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For memory leaks, you can use Instruments, comes with the Developer tools. Also, you can use “Analyze” to get XCode to show you any possible leaks (Cmd-Shift-B).

Comment: Hi, thanks! Do you mind sharing with me more details on how to use instruments? Do I need to enable any settings?

Comment: I’m quite new to iOS development, so I don’t know that much about any specific settings etc. I just run with the defaults.

Comment: @Zhen: @margusholland: Here is the good tutorial to use leak tool(for both of you ..:)..) http://mobileorchard.com/find-iphone-memory-leaks-a-leaks-tool-tutorial/

Comment: This one too is good [How to debug](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2696/how-to-debug-memory-leaks-with-xcode-and-instruments-tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

you can use "NSZombieEnabled" to track your EXC_BAD_ACCESS problem(it'll give you some details of badly accessed objects), [how to use it?](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSZombieEnabled), and also refer this link(very consitently) [Break on EXC_BAD_ACCESS in XCode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622079/break-on-exc-bad-access-in-xcode/1622091#1622091)